# R - Getting individual characteristics from panel dataset

Tags: r

I have a data set of individuals repeatedly observed overtime for example:

```
Name    Year  Income State Gender   
Alice    1        40    NY  Female
Alice    2        55    NY  Female
Bob      1        30    WA  Male
Bob      2        22    WA  Male
```

I'd like to make a new data.frame that describes the individual characteristics  that I know stay the same.  Something like:

```
Name  State Gender
Alice  NY    Female
Bob    WA    Male
```

How would I do this in R?

Comment: I am assuming the second row from the expected output would be `Bob WA male`.

Comment: Yes, I've edited my question to make the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Getting the `unique` of the data.frame with the columns you want will do it:

```
unique(df[c('Name', 'State', 'Gender')])
#   Name State Gender
#1 Alice    NY Female
#3   Bob    WA   Male
```